# regex select multiple groups

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string from which I want to extract the content between the second pair of colons (in bold in the example):

"20160607181026_0000005:0607181026000000501:**ES5206956802492**:479"

I am using R and specifically the stringr package to manipulate strings.
The command I attempted to use is:

str_extract("20160607181026_0000005:0607181026000000501:ES5206956802492:479", ":(.*):")

where the regex pattern is expressed at the end of the command. This produces the following result:

":0607181026000000501:ES5206956802492:"

I know that there is a way of grouping results and back-reference them, which would allow me to select only the part I am interested in, but I don't seem to be able to figure out the right syntax.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first character after the `:` starts with `LETTERS`, then we can use a compact regex.  Here, we use regex lookaround (`(?<=:)`) and match a LETTERS (`[A-Z]`) that follows the `:` followed by one of more characters that are not a `:` (`[^:]+`).

```
str_extract(v1, "(?<=:)[A-Z][^:]+")
#[1] "ES5206956802492"
```

---

or if it is based on the position i.e. 2nd position, a `base R` option would be to match zero or more non `:` (`[^:]*`) followed by the first `:` followed by zero or more non `:` followed by the second `:` and then we capture the non `:` in a group (`(...)`) and followed by rest of the characters (`.*`).  In the replacement, we use the backreference, i.e. `\\1` (first capture group).

```
sub("[^:]*:[^:]*:([^:]+).*", "\\1", v1)
#[1] "ES5206956802492"
```

Or the repeating part can be captured to make it compact

```
sub("([^:]*:){2}([^:]+).*", "\\2", v1)
#[1] "ES5206956802492"
```

Or with `strsplit`, we split at delimiter `:` and extract the 3rd element.

```
strsplit(v1, ":")[[1]][3]
#[1] "ES5206956802492"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "20160607181026_0000005:0607181026000000501:ES5206956802492:479"
```

Comment: That's great @akrun. Could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: @thepule I added some explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Also `word` from `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
word(v1, 3, sep=':')
#[1] "ES5206956802492"
```

Comment: Hmm, the `word` again :-)

Comment: hehehe...this time I got the hint from your `strsplit` approach :)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel it is trending :)

Comment: Haha that is a neat solution indeed.